# Reduce text that is displayed from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

On the first page I want to limit the `$row['opis']` to 100 chars, but user have possibility to type 500 chars, so I need to limit `$row['opis']` in first page. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
<?php
                            mysql_connect("localhost","root","123") or die(mysql_error());
                            mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
                            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC";
                            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

                        echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 masonry-grid-item">
                                    <div class="listing-item">
                                    <div class="overlay-container">
                                        <img src="images/product-1.png" alt="">
                                        <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="overlay small">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                            <span>View Details</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="listing-item-body clearfix">
                                        <h3 class="title"><a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'. $row['naziv'] .'</a></h3>
                                        <p>' . $row['opis'] . '</p>
                                        <span class="price">' . $row['tel'] . '</span>
                                        <div class="elements-list pull-right">
                                            <a href="#" class="wishlist" title="wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                                            <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Pogledaj</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

                            }
                            mysql_close();
                        ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I need from ' $opis ' 100 , write inquiry?

Comment: use "LIMIT" in your sql query (0,100, 101,200, ...) depending on a "GET" value (add a "page" nav in your page, if there are 100+ charts), when user will click on "next page", that should trigger "YOURPAGE&p=2" for example... or use POST... your question is not really clear to me..., I think you want to limit records number in page display but I'm not even sure of it^^, need more information/details...

Comment: Question is, how to add substring to display only 100 charts, if user insert comment with 500 charts, how to on first page display only 100 with 3 dots?

Comment: ok^^ then check your chart length (with .length() i think), then do something like yourItem.substr(100,(yourItem.length-100))+"..." (first numer is substr start index, then second number is number of "removed" chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mb_strimwidth, to show first 100 characters

```
<?php
                            mysql_connect("localhost","root","123") or die(mysql_error());
                            mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
                            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC";
                            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

                        echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 masonry-grid-item">
                                    <div class="listing-item">
                                    <div class="overlay-container">
                                        <img src="images/product-1.png" alt="">
                                        <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="overlay small">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                            <span>View Details</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="listing-item-body clearfix">
                                        <h3 class="title"><a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'. $row['naziv'] .'</a></h3>
                                        <p>' . mb_strimwidth($row["opis"], 0, 100, "") . '</p>
                                        <span class="price">' . $row['tel'] . '</span>
                                        <div class="elements-list pull-right">
                                            <a href="#" class="wishlist" title="wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                                            <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Pogledaj</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

                            }
                            mysql_close();
                        ?>
```

**Explanation:**

`mb_strimwidth($YOUR_STRING, 0, 100, "")`

`0` means that the trim starts from the first character, and `100` is the limit of characters. Fourth option allows you to add something like "..." at the end of the new string.

**Edit**

You can also use `substr` but it is counting using bytes, and not characters. So if you are using some multi-byte encoding, like UTF-8 (Greek, Serbian, Romanian etc), you should use `mb_strimwidth` as above.

Answer (score 1):

NETCreator Thanks a lot!

Answer is add mb_strimwidth($YOUR_STRING, 0, 100, "")...

```
<?php
                        mysql_connect("localhost","root","123") or die(mysql_error());
                        mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
                        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC";
                        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

                    echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 masonry-grid-item">
                                <div class="listing-item">
                                <div class="overlay-container">
                                    <img src="images/product-1.png" alt="">
                                    <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="overlay small">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        <span>View Details</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="listing-item-body clearfix">
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'. $row['naziv'] .'</a></h3>
                                    <p>' . mb_strimwidth($row["opis"], 0, 100, "") . '</p>
                                    <span class="price">' . $row['tel'] . '</span>
                                    <div class="elements-list pull-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="wishlist" title="wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                                        <a href="oglas/index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Pogledaj</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';

                        }
                        mysql_close();
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr also.. the below code display first 4 characters.

```
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);
```

output 
`abcd`

Answer (score 0):

@Mile you can do like this to

```
$text = substr($text,$start,$length);
```

here `$text` is your string, `$start` is your starting point and `$length` is how long you want to show a string.